# how to upload a file with tier glacier flaxible by default

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I have been trying to upload a file with the tier glacier flexible pattern, however it always comes in as the default. How can I fix this?

Follow my methods, both from a single file and from a directory

Single File

```
@Override
    public ResponseEntity<String>uploadFiles(MultipartFile file) {
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = null;
        try {
            
            String data = file.getOriginalFilename().substring(0, 8);
            
            final String fileName = data + "/" + file.getOriginalFilename();
             PutObjectRequest objectRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder()
                        .bucket(BUCKETNAME)
                        .key(fileName)
                        .build();
            
             s3Client.putObject(objectRequest, RequestBody.fromBytes(file.getBytes()));
             
             responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<String>(new Gson().toJson("Upload realizado"), HttpStatus.OK);
             LOGGER.info("[AwsS3BucketService] Info - Upload File: Success" );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<String>(new Gson().toJson("Falha ao realizar o upload do arquivo"), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
             LOGGER.info("[AwsS3BucketService] Info - Upload File: Fail " + e.getMessage() );
        }
        return responseEntity;
    }
```

Upload Directory

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity<String> uploadDirectory(String folderPath ) {
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = null;
    //String folder = folderPath.substring(folderPath.length()-8);
        try {
            
             DirectoryUpload directoryUpload =
                        transferManager.uploadDirectory(UploadDirectoryRequest.builder()
                            .source(Paths.get(folderPath).getParent())
                            .bucket(BUCKETNAME)
                            .build());
            
                    CompletedDirectoryUpload completedDirectoryUpload = directoryUpload.completionFuture().join();
                    completedDirectoryUpload.failedTransfers().forEach(fail ->
                    LOGGER.info("Object [{}] failed to transfer", fail.toString()));
                    
                    responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<String>(new Gson().toJson("Upload realizado"), HttpStatus.OK);
                
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<String>(new Gson().toJson("Falha ao realizar o upload do diretório"), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
             LOGGER.info("[AwsS3BucketService] Info - Upload directory: Fail " + e.getMessage() );
        }
    
    return responseEntity;
}
```

New Method using Glacier, but i have no ideia if this approach correctly

```
@Override
    public ResponseEntity<String> uploadDirectory(String folderPath ) {

        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = null;
        
        // Get an SHA-256 tree hash value.
        //String checkVal = computeSHA256(myFile);
        try {
            
            UploadArchiveRequest uploadRequest = UploadArchiveRequest.builder()
                .vaultName(BUCKETNAME)
                //.checksum(checkVal)
                .build();

            UploadArchiveResponse res = glacier.uploadArchive(uploadRequest, Paths.get(folderPath));
          
            responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<String>(new Gson().toJson("Upload realizado"), HttpStatus.OK);

        } catch(GlacierException e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<String>(new Gson().toJson("Falha ao realizar o upload do diretório"), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return responseEntity;
    }
```

Comment: Where is your code setting the desired Storage Class?

Comment: That's the point, I have no idea where to define this.
I created a new method looking directly at Glacier, but I don't know if it's the right approach.

Comment: You can add `.storageClass(StorageClass.GLACIER)` to your `PutObjectRequest.builder()`. See valid values at: [StorageClass (AWS SDK for Java)](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/model/StorageClass.html)